# Zimbra - 'Some services are not running'

Tags: centos6, service, zimbra

I installed Zimbra Collaboration Open Source Edition 8.5.0 in a Centos 6 Virtual Machine.
Zimbra is up and running and all the services are up and running.

```
#>service zimbra status
Host test.mail.com
amavis                  Running
antispam                Running
antivirus               Running
dnscache                Running
ldap                    Running
logger                  Running
mailbox                 Running
memcached               Running
mta                     Running
opendkim                Running
proxy                   Running
service webapp          Running
snmp                    Running
spell                   Running
stats                   Running
zimbra webapp           Running
zimbraAdmin webapp      Running
zimlet webapp           Running
zmconfigd               Running
```

But unfortunately in Zimbra Administration I get this error message: "Some services are not running". In Server status there are some services which are not running like: amavis, antispam, zimbra, zimbraAdmin, zimlet.

How can I make them running also in ZimbraAdmin?

Answer (score 2):

When zimbra was not correctly shut down, it is possible that there are stale pid-files.
This information can be found in the zimbra log /var/log/zimbra

`mail amavis[13235]: Ignoring stale PID file /opt/zimbra/log/amavisd.pid, older than system uptime 0 0:13:00
(!)Net::Server: Pid_file already exists for running process (2684)... aborting\n\n`

Stop zimbra, remove the stale pid file and then start it again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed you server clock recently? If yes then check this post ..

http://forums.zimbra.com/administrators/33210-solved-web-admin-ui-server-status-offline-7.html

I had same issue. What I did was I changed my clock and after that zimbra stop showing monitoring results including service status as well.

I followed the steps list in the post and finally my zimbra start to work fine. Check the last post in that forum.